# Postgres database going crazy after upgrade from 9.0 to 9.3, cpu/ram

Tags: performance, postgresql

I upgraded my postgres database from 9.0 to 9.3 and imported the data from one to the other (about 2gigs).

Since the import the new database has been going crazy taking 30% cpu and 4 gig ram, tried rebooting, and leaving it for a day, but still going crazy any ideas?

** update **

Some more info.

Nothing is running on the database, no queries, etc.
It seems to be related to the vacuum process.  If I disable the vacuum, then it is fine.
Perhaps it takes vacuum a while to clean up after a big import (2 gig .sql file, ~500 databases), but it is still going crazy after 2 days, which seems like some kind of bug?

Comment: Did you run `vacuum` or `vacuum analyze` on the database after importing the data?

Comment: More details will help your chances of getting an answer. What is running in the cluster when it is going "crazy"? Is it a single query? Lots of queries? Is there something in common between the queries? Postgres the query plan of one of the more egregious ones.

Comment: What's running on the server? How is postgres configured? How much data are you accessing and how much RAM do you have? Generally, the upgrade should show performance improvement, not degradation, so it's hard to tell with the information provided and any answer here would be a guess at most.

Comment: Closevoted. This question is lacking any information required to help you - and you've been around here long enough to know how to write a decent question. Was the upgrade with `pg_dump` (implied by "imported the data"), `pg_upgrade`, other? What platform are you on? What is the workload the database is working on? What's in the logs and `pg_stat_activity`? What's in `top` (sorted by RAM, sorted by CPU). Did you change any config params during the migration, use the default config for the new Pg as-is, copy the config for the old Pg over, ... ? What upgrade process did you follow EXACTLY?

Comment: I did not run vacuum explictly, how do I do this?

Comment: Log into any database and issue `VACUUM VERBOSE`. Docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Comment: I ran this on a couple of the databases, and didn't change anything.  There are over 500 databases, do I need to do this on all of them? (how?)

Comment: Did you read that docs link I supplied? It talks about the `vacuumdb` program. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-vacuumdb.html

Comment: With over 500 databases you may be seeing some kind of bug to do with pg statisitics gathering.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran,

```
vacuumdb --all --full -w
```

After making a pgpass.conf file in, C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Roaming\postgresql.  This took a while, but its seems somewhat better now.

Postgres is still trashing the disk, but is down to 10% cpu instead of 30%, and only 30meg ram instead of 4gig.

Think that I might just disable the vacuum and just run it manually once a month...